# MVC5 Route Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently upgraded from MVC 5 to MVC 3. I never registred a route, however, this URL worked:

http://www.testsite.com/shipworks/index/myemail@yahoo.com?website=testsite.com

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string id, string website)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;
    }
```

I now get a 404 with this code. I tried this route, however, it also fails:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
"ShipWorks", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}/{website}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "ShipWorks", action = "Index", email = UrlParameter.Optional, website =     
UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "CloudCartConnector.Web.Controllers" }// Parameter defaults
);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I put the shipping route above the default one. Note that my id is a string. The URL works fine with ?id=myemail@myemail.com.

Comment: If a route *appears* not to work, you need to list **all** your routes in the order you are adding them.

Comment: `shipping/index/{id}` won't work as there's no "index" in your URL. Try `shipping/{id}` instead...

Comment: Thanks. I tried Index and I listed the routes. I still see a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach.**
According to your path:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}/{website}"
```

you don't need to specify explicitly "website" property name. Then, you marked in your route that `{id}` and `{website}` are separated by slash `/`, so correct use of your route mask should be `http://www.testsite.com/shipworks/index/myemail@yahoo.com/testsite.com`.
However, here is one problem - dot symbol `.` will not be recognized correctly (in the way you want). So if you remove the dot, the path `http://www.testsite.com/shipworks/index/myemail@yahoo.com/testsitecom` will work.

**Second approach.**
In order to reach the results you want, you'd better pass e-mail and website as the query parameter, not as the part of the path.
You can use the following route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShipWorks", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "ShipWorks",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }, new[] { "CloudCartConnector.Web.Controllers" }// Parameter defaults
);
```

Controller's action:

```
//[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string email, string website)
{
    (...)
    return View();
}
```

And the query string: `http://www.testsite.com/shipworks/index?email=myemail@yahoo.com&website=testsite.com`.

Please note also, that since you marked your `Index` method with `[HttpPost]` attribute, you will get `404` using `GET` method (like typing in browser) even if you have correct URL.

Comment: Second approach still had dot in the path, it's OK now